# nginx reverse proxy to google cloud function?

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-platform

So far tried, but could not get a valid response from their endpoint (ssl handshake fails)

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name xxx;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx/privkey.pem;
    ssl_session_timeout 24h;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'xxx';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    resolver 127.0.0.1;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=31536000;
    ssl_dhparam /xxx/dhparam.pem;
    location / {
      proxy_pass https://us-central1-project_id.cloudfunctions.net;
    }
}
```

Getting the following :

```
... peer closed connection in SSL handshake while SSL handshaking to upstream...
```

Fetching the enpoint with openssl (`openssl s_client -connect us-central1-project_id.cloudfunctions.net:443`) returns the following :

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
139669452420760:error:140790E5:SSL routines:ssl23_write:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:177:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 305 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1493734932
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

I don't really know how to analyze such responses

Does setting such reverse proxy in general (to an ssl endpoints) require specific setup ? Or is it just google preventing users from this kind of use ?

Comment: Your line "ssl_ciphers 'xxx';" seems like it could be a problem. You'll want to use the most compatible set, for testing. Try the legacy set from https://cipherli.st/

Comment: long string so i've cut it short; it is one of those show on your link

Answer (score 1):

You need to give nginx some client credentials to use so it can do an SSL handshake. There are no defaults for that; you need to explicitly provide these.

Interacting with the Google API itself will likely require more than that, possibly authentication with a Bearer token and other header manipulation. It's likely you'll need to manipulate headers, so be prepared to spend some time finding out what headers need to look like for this API and make sure that's what you're sending.

When forwarding headers, add `underscores_in_headers on` to your server block to avoid sending invalid headers.

Summing up, here's a basic config for this sort of thing:

```
server {
  ...
  # Server ssl directives
  ...
  # Avoid sending invalid headers
  underscores_in_headers on;
  ...
  location / {
     proxy_pass https://us-central1-project_id.cloudfunctions.net/;

     # Client SSL certificate
     proxy_ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/my_client.pem;
     proxy_ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/my_client.key;

     # Header configurations for google API
     proxy_pass_request_headers   on;
     proxy_set_header             Authorization: Bearer [bearer-id];
  }
}
```

Comment: I'll try this out. In case, and here, i'm talking about google cloud functions (still beta, equivalent to amazon lambda), and those are plain public https endpoints

Comment: The cert/key specified in the location block, what are they ? Self signed ones generatd locally ?

Comment: You can use self-signed if google will accept that. Maybe use curl to test. In a production context, it's a security risk (man-in-the-middle) but it's worth trying, IMO, as you get the pipeline working.

Comment: I lack of knowledge i guess; would letsencrypt certs would work ? And in that scope, which domain should be specified ?

Comment: @Ben - You can generate your own client certs with openssl. Here's [a walkthrough of how to do that](https://gist.github.com/mtigas/952344).

Answer (score 0):

In order to proxy_pass to a google cloud (gcp) function, you must tell nginx (Nginx version 1.7+) to use SNI with the following directives in your location block:

```
    proxy_ssl_server_name on;
    proxy_ssl_name $proxy_host;
```

In order to call google cloud functions you must do so specifying [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) since the function does not reside at a static ip address. Nginx, by default, does not send SNI information to the upstream.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_ssl_server_name

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that worked for me.

replace SUBDOMAIN.DOMAIN.COM with your URL

```
     proxy_set_header Host SUBDOMAIN.DOMAIN.COM;
     proxy_ssl_server_name on;
```